# How to make an item in ScrollView take up the height of the entire screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm developing an **watchOS** app using **SwiftUI**. It's my first time using SwiftUI and developing an watchOS app.

I want to create a `ScrollView` which contains 2 Views, each of which should have the same height as the entire screen.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewContainer_swift: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            DetailView()
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollViewContainer_swift_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollViewContainer_swift()
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("This should take up the height of the entire screen.")
            Spacer()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .all)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView()
    }
}
```

Using `ignoresSafeArea`, I could make a single `DetailView` to take up the full height. The result of `DetailView_Previews` looks like this:

[image]

However, if I put it into the `ScrollView`, the `DetailView`s seem to shrink to the minimum height:

[image]

I have tried the followings, but none of these seemed to do the trick.

- `DetailView().frame(maxHeight: .infinity)`
- `DetailView().ignoresSafeArea()`
- `ScrollView().ignoresSafeArea()`

Forcing the height of the view like `DetailView().frame(height: 170)` did similar to what I want to achieve, but it obviously cannot adapt to various screen sizes.

Is there anything else I can try?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? Right now, people would have to go through and replace all the … in your code to get a compiling example to experiment with.

Comment: @jnpdx My bad. I included a minimal reproducible example and rewrote the post. Thanks for the advice. Please let me know if there's anything else that I need to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, the `ScrollView` will take up all available space in *one* screen. Then, the `DetailView` will only take up as much space as it needs. Even with the `Spacer`s, it won't expand vertically because the `ScrollView` isn't imposing a size constraint on it.

In order to get the `DetailView`s to be the size of the screen, you can use a `GeometryReader` and then pass down the height to the child views:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    DetailView().frame(height: proxy.size.height)
                    DetailView().frame(height: proxy.size.height)
                }
            }
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("This should take up the height of the entire screen.")
            Spacer()
        }
        //.frame(maxWidth: .infinity) //add this if you want the view to extend to the horizontal edges
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: As answered below, I would strongly consider against using `GeometryReader` for a rather simple layout task like that.

Answer (score 0):

`GeometryReader` has it's place but for what was asked here, it's most probably the wrong tool. Regarding `GeometryReader` there are at least two things to consider:

1. It can have performance drawbacks
2. It might alter your layout. Eventually you can get into other issues depending on how the view is build up and how SwiftUI refreshes the view

For aligning heights of elements you most probably can achieve it with a combination of
`.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on the container and  `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` on the element's itself.

Here is a pretty small example:

```swift
HStack {
    VStack {
        Text("We")
        Text("don't")
        Text("need")
        Text("GeometryReader")
    }
    .background(Color.blue)
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

    Text("Only One Line")
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
}
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

[image: Screenshot of resulting view of the code above]

Further reading:

- https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-equal-height-hstack/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/y1as70/is_swiftui_geometryreader_bad/

Comment: This solution doesn’t actually lead to the result the OP asks about, though.